# Check if node has already been published in Umbraco 6.1.4 asp.net c#?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, umbraco

Is there a way to check if node in Umbraco ( v. 6.1.5) content has already been published or how many times node has been published, so that, if this is, for example, second time to press "publish" on same node, I can apply some logic?

I need that count of publishing for translating, so that I can update text in content in node of other language, since MS Translator works only when node that I want to translate is first time published.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a little work but you could add a `publishedCount` label property to your doc type, and then increment this value each time you save with the following code:

```
public class SaveEvent : ApplicationEventHandler
{

    protected override void ApplicationStarted(UmbracoApplicationBase umbracoApplication, ApplicationContext applicationContext)
    {
        ContentService.Saving += ContentService_Saving;
    }

    void ContentService_Saving(IContentService sender, SaveEventArgs<IContent> e)
    {
        foreach (var item in e.SavedEntities)
        {
            if (!item.HasProperty("publishedCount"))
                return;

            int workingCount = item.GetValue<int>("publishedCount");                              
            item.SetValue("publishedCount", workingCount++);

            if(workingCount => 1)
            {
                // do additional work here
            }
       }
    }


}
```

Your published nodes will always then have a publishedCount property that you can check.

You can find further information at http://our.umbraco.org/wiki/reference and any speific implementation questions could be asked at http://our.umbraco.org too.

Answer (score 0):

You best bet is going to write hook into the publish events for Umbraco then get the node id of the document being published. In the database there is a table which stores the data used build the Umbraco audit trail ( not sure which one it is ) and in there you can check when the document was last published or how many times then add your language logic there. See the threads below fr references:
[example of a publish event hook](http://our.umbraco.org/forum/developers/api-questions/7266-How-to-get-currentNode-in-the-PublishEventHandler?p=1)

[Overview of all events in umbraco](http://our.umbraco.org/wiki/reference/api-cheatsheet/using-applicationbase-to-register-events/overview-of-all-events)